# How to convert indentation to space in Vim?

Tags: vim

I typed following command in vim to show white space characters, such as eol, tab, and space.

```
:set listchars=eol:$,nbsp:_,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
```

This file was cloned from git repository.  Indentation is setup for tabs.  How do I convert indentation to space?

```
 50 addtask listtasks$
 51 do_listtasks[nostamp] = "1"$
 52 python do_listtasks() {$
 53 >-import sys$
 54   print('Hello World')$
 55 >-for e in bb.data.keys(d):$
 56 >->-if d.getVarFlag(e, 'task', False):$
 57 >->->-bb.plain("%s" % e)$
 58 }$
```

Comment: Answer from another forum                                                                                                  %s/\t/    /g

Answer (score 0):

Use the `retab` command on the whole buffer:

```
:%retab
```

to change tabs to their equivalent number of spaces. Afterwards, you may want to reindent some sections (using `=`).

Set `expandtab` to have tabs automatically replaced with spaces when you type them.